# How to make the navigation bar scroll with the webview as the safari in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, safari, uinavigationbar

Just as the effect of the safari browser in iOS, When the web page is scolled down, the navigaton bar go down together, as the web page is scolled up, the navigation go out from the view, how to impletement like this?
Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

You should make that navigation bar the table header view (not to be confused with a section header view). A table view has a property, tableHeaderView, which you can set to any custom view you want. It will appear at the top of the table view, and will scroll with it.